# Set transparent background when cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to set default background (`#fff`) if cell is empty after I edit it.
Cell background must be transparent after:

- I choose cell -> press <kbd>Enter</kbd> -> backspace all cell content -> press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- I choose cell -> clear cell's value by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>.

What I've tried:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;

  if (e.value == '') {
    range.setBackground('#fff');
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the active cell becomes the empty by deleting the value, `e` of `onEdit(e)` has no `value` as the key as follows. So how about this modification?

#### From :

```
if (e.value == '') {
```

#### To :

```
if (!e.value) {
```

#### Samples

**Put a value**

When "sample value" is put to the cell "A1", `e` of `onEdit(e)` returns the following object.

```
{
  "authMode": {},
  "range": {
    "columnStart": 1,
    "rowStart": 1,
    "rowEnd": 1,
    "columnEnd": 1
  },
  "source": {},
  "user": {
    "nickname": "### name ###",
    "email": "### email ###"
  },
  "value": "sample value"
}
```

**Delete a value**

When the value of cell "A1" is deleted, `e` of `onEdit(e)` returns the following object. You can see that there is no key of `value`.

```
{
  "authMode": {},
  "range": {
    "columnStart": 1,
    "rowStart": 1,
    "rowEnd": 1,
    "columnEnd": 1
  },
  "source": {},
  "user": {
    "nickname": "### name ###",
    "email": "### email ###"
  }
}
```